# No Title or Cancel Button for MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a MFMessageComposeViewController from a UIActivityViewController. However, when I select to share using a Message I see this[image: message screen without cancel]

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["text"], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I customized my navigation bar appearance in my AppDelegate

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Using Mail does not have this problem

Comment: You should change the appearance for bar button item. Instead of UInavigationbar

Comment: @YogeshMv `UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Normal)` did not work either